# Group date and Pivot in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sum, pivot

I'm stuck with my SQL request. 
I want to get sum of a column named MONTANT for each day and each store's number.

My SQL request is :

```
SELECT DATE AS 'JOUR', "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"

FROM ticket_reglement

UP PIVOT (SUM(MONTANT) FOR NUMERO_CAISSE IN ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")) AS pvt 

WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2015-12-07' AND '2015-12-13'
```

Numbers from 1 to 5 are store's number I want to pivot.
This request works but the 'JOUR' columns (which contains dates) contains several times each day. For exemple :

```
  JOUR      |  1  |  2  |  3  |
____________|_____|_____|_____|
 07/12/2015 |  5  |  0  |  1  |
 07/12/2015 |  3  |  2  |  0  |
 08/12/2015 |  1  |  0  |  3  |
```

How can I change my request to get the sum for each day ? (one line for one day)

I also want the same request for MySQL but unfortunately UP PIVOT is not existing for MySQL. I have searched some questions about that but don't find a real answer to an alternative way.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use `GROUP BY DATE` in the query

Comment: GROUP BY DATE doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT [DATE], MONTANT, NUMERO_CAISSE
    FROM dbo.ticket_reglement
) t
PIVOT (
    COUNT(MONTANT)
    FOR NUMERO_CAISSE IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5]) 
) p
```

update -

```
SELECT
     `DATE`
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN `NUMERO_CAISSE` = 1 THEN 1 END) AS `1`
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN `NUMERO_CAISSE` = 2 THEN 1 END) AS `2`
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN `NUMERO_CAISSE` = 3 THEN 1 END) AS `3`
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN `NUMERO_CAISSE` = 4 THEN 1 END) AS `4`
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN `NUMERO_CAISSE` = 5 THEN 1 END) AS `5`
FROM ticket_reglement
GROUP BY `DATE`
```

Comment: This work as I want for SQL Server. I just have to replace COUNT by SUM but thank you a lot. I am still not well accustomed with PIVOT.

Do you have an idea how I can replace PIVOT with MySQL ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and your replies